# Google Map searching using java code

Tags: java, google-maps, jsp, gis

Requirement: 
1. jsp page contains a field that having a search button. 
2. When I click on search, it should send a Http request and Response page should be of Google Map 
3. That Google Map should zoom into particular Location, whatever I have typed in Search field. 
Please tell me how to write, because I new to this. 
And please tell me some tutorials where I can learn Completely about Java Code which is related to Google Map.

Comment: What sort of search?  Is it free form, or select from a list?  If it's a list, do you have the lat/long of the locations?

Comment: Yes, it is free form.Example: typing 'India' and clicking on search, then it should Locate(zoom) and show India in Google Map